# Adding a table cell with an anchor tag that fits it’s height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to create a table with a link (an anchor tag) taking the full height of the table cell (td) that contains it.

This works in Firefox:

```
table tr,
table td {
    height: 100%;
}

table td > a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6nem4/

With a couple of minor edits it also starts to work in Chrome, Safari, etc:

```
table tr,
table td {
    height: 100%;
}

table td > a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sj3ST/

I’m just curious if there is a way of making it also work in IE10.

Comment: You can add padding to the anchor tag...in IE

Answer (score 0):

Not the best idea: http://jsfiddle.net/sj3ST/1/

But add padding in IE to anchor tag

```
a{
   padding: 56px 0;
 }
```

Or give padding to span

Comment: The problem with this solution is that a static padding value is only suitable when we can rely on the height of the parent element (i.e. it isn’t dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link to appear in the top of the `td` add `vertical-align: top;` to your `td.link` and also the background color you want to the `td` and not the link itself.

If you want the link to appear in the middlw just remove the `vertical-align` property from my example.

**OR**

You can use add `padding-top: 50%; padding-bottom: 50%;` to the `a`

**OR**

You can just use a `div` instead of `a` element and set `onClick` event.

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/sj3ST/4/)**

Comment: Thank you. Actually, that is quite close. The whole table cell is painted in the anchor tag’s colour, but the clickable area is not expanded (the size of the clickable area is the size of the anchor tag’s content plus padding).